# Why does this async function not return anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a function that needs to run when my app starts. It basically makes several API calls to fetch the user's information, count its messages and subscribe to a socket channel.

It is made with React-query. But it doesn't perform any API call. The function `_getUserInformations` is never triggered and the network tab of my inspector remains void.

The server has no issues and the routes work. Here is the code:

```
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    initializeUser();
  }, []);
  const user = userStore();
  
  return routes + app
  );
}

export const initializeUser = () => {
  try {
    const res = await getUserInformations();
    const user = res.data.user;
    updateUser(user);
    const { unreadConversations } = await hasUnreadConversations(user._id);
    updateunreadConversations(unreadConversations);
    getNotifications(user._id);
  } 
  catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
};

const _getUserInformations = async () => {
  try {
    const userToken = await api.get("/user-informations", {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    return userToken;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err.message || "error.unknown");
  }
};

const getUserInformations: UserService["getUserInformations"] = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery("getUserInfos", () => _getUserInformations(), {
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // 24 hours
  });
  return data.data.user;
};
```

What is wrong here?

Here is also a sandbox that reproduces the same issue with PokeApi: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-hill-tei88?file=/src/App.js

`_getPokemon` (that imitates `_getUserInformations`) is never called as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hooks should only be used in a functional component.

For example in your codesandbox codes, if you use the following, it will work.

```
export default function App() {
  const { data, isError } = useQuery("getpokemon", () => _getPokemon());
  console.log('data', data) //you can see the data printed.
  React.useEffect(() => initialize(), []);


  if (!data && !isError) return <Loading /> // Bonus Tip - data is fetching if both data and isError is undefined.

  return <div>hello</div>;
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from custom
> Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).

Also...

> ### Only Call Hooks at the Top Level Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top
>
> level of your React function, before any early returns. By following
> this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each
> time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly
> preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect
> calls. (If you’re curious, we’ll explain this in depth below.)

Comment: the answer is correct, but the Bonus Tip (data is fetching if both data and isError is undefined) is not ideal. If you get an error, react-query will go to error state and give you the error. if you then re-fetch, you will be in loading state, but you'll still have the "old" error, because those are not deleted. using the status field or the derived status booleans, or performing explicit checks (show data if you have data, no matter the state), are the preferred patterns.

Comment: You are correct. However, re-fetching is in the background. Showing the error is also mandatory when error occur so user know what is happening. In most cases, fetching mechanism should only return error when it's 4xx and 5xx which in most case, is a failed-fetch which cannot be recovered by refetching